# ¿Cómo incluir condicional para evaluar un valor numércio dentro de un ciclo while?

Tags: php, while, mpdf

Pretendo incluir un condicional dentro de un ciclo while, con el cual obtengo y pinto los items en una tabla HTML. Pero requiero evaluar si un valor es igual o diferente a cero y dependiendo de ello debo calcular y mostrar correctamente el valor esperado:

```
$html = '
<tbody>';
      while($row = $consultaDetalleFactura->fetch_assoc())
      {
        $html .=
        '
        <tr  tyle="height:500px;">
            <th scope="row">'
             .  $fila++ .
            '</th>
            <td class="text-left">' . $row['codigo_producto'] . '</td>
            <td class="text-left">' . $row['nombre_producto'] . '</td>
            <td class="text-center">' . $row['cantidad_detalle_factura'] . '</td>
            <td class="text-center">' . $row['descuento_detalle_factura'] . '</td>
            <td class="text-center">' . $row['valor_impuesto'] . '%</td>
            <td class="text-right">$'
            .
              if ($row['valor_impuesto'] != 0)
                number_format(((($row['costo_venta_detalle_factura'] * $row['cantidad_detalle_factura']) - (($row['costo_venta_detalle_factura'] * $row['cantidad_detalle_factura'] * $row['descuento_detalle_factura'])/100)) * $row['calculo_impuesto']))
              else
                number_format(((($row['costo_venta_detalle_factura'] * $row['cantidad_detalle_factura']) - (($row['costo_venta_detalle_factura'] * $row['cantidad_detalle_factura'] * $row['descuento_detalle_factura'])/100))))
            .
            '</td>
        </tr>';
      }
        $html .='
      </tbody>
';
```

Debo saber si el impuesto del producto es igual a cero (en mi país hay productos que están exceptuados del pago del impuesto pero aun así está gravado con dicho impuesto, que en este caso sería cero). Por lo que al multiplicar el cero con lo restante de mi formula, su resultado sería cero.

**Error**

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in C:\Users\Johan
>   Corrales\Documents\GitHub\angular\api\Class\PDF2\prueba.php on line
>   425

¿Cuál sería la forma o fórmula correcta de calcular dicho valor dentro del ciclo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Opción 1

Realizar el calculo fuera de la concatenación (*código simple y legible*).

```
$html = '
<tbody>';
      while($row = $consultaDetalleFactura->fetch_assoc())
      {

          // Calculo
          $impuesto = ($row['valor_impuesto'] == 0) ? 1 : $row['valor_impuesto'];
          $total = number_format(((($row['costo_venta_detalle_factura'] * $row['cantidad_detalle_factura']) - (($row['costo_venta_detalle_factura'] * $row['cantidad_detalle_factura'] * $row['descuento_detalle_factura'])/100)) * $impuesto));

          $html .=
        '
        <tr  tyle="height:500px;">
            <th scope="row">' .  $fila++ . '</th>
            <td class="text-left">' . $row['codigo_producto'] . '</td>
            <td class="text-left">' . $row['nombre_producto'] . '</td>
            <td class="text-center">' . $row['cantidad_detalle_factura'] . '</td>
            <td class="text-center">' . $row['descuento_detalle_factura'] . '</td>
            <td class="text-center">' . $row['valor_impuesto'] . '%</td>
            <td class="text-right">$' . $total . '</td>
        </tr>';
      }
        $html .='
      </tbody>
';
```

---

#### Opción 2

Usar el [operador ternario](http://php.net/manual/es/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) dentro de la concatenación.

```
$html = '
<tbody>';
      while($row = $consultaDetalleFactura->fetch_assoc())
      {

          $html .=
        '
        <tr  tyle="height:500px;">
            <th scope="row">' .  $fila++ . '</th>
            <td class="text-left">' . $row['codigo_producto'] . '</td>
            <td class="text-left">' . $row['nombre_producto'] . '</td>
            <td class="text-center">' . $row['cantidad_detalle_factura'] . '</td>
            <td class="text-center">' . $row['descuento_detalle_factura'] . '</td>
            <td class="text-center">' . $row['valor_impuesto'] . '%</td>
            <td class="text-right">$' . (
              ($row['valor_impuesto'] != 0) ?
              number_format(((($row['costo_venta_detalle_factura'] * $row['cantidad_detalle_factura']) - (($row['costo_venta_detalle_factura'] * $row['cantidad_detalle_factura'] * $row['descuento_detalle_factura'])/100)) * $row['calculo_impuesto'])) :
              number_format(((($row['costo_venta_detalle_factura'] * $row['cantidad_detalle_factura']) - (($row['costo_venta_detalle_factura'] * $row['cantidad_detalle_factura'] * $row['descuento_detalle_factura'])/100))))
            ) . '</td>
        </tr>';
      }
        $html .='
      </tbody>
';
```

Comment: Hola @Marcos, tenías razón con la opción 1, no lo había pensado de esa manera, muchas gracias!